# Generate HTML Canvas from AngularJS Template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, canvas

I am trying to render html element on canvas using html2canvas JS. But I am using AngularJS for data binding on html page and the dynamic data is not rendered on generated canvas from these html elements. For example, I have an html element like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>URI</th>
        <th>Is Default</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="printer in printers">
        <td>{{printer.name}}</td>
        <td>{{printer.url}}</td>
        <td>{{printer.default}}</td>
        <td><button ng-click="printTestPage(printer.url)">Print Test Page</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But we can see that the dynamic data is not rendered on canvas:

[image]
Any suggestions regarding how to do it properly, with or without using html2canvas js???

Answer (score 0):

When do you call the html2canvas? 
You should call the function after the dom renderd

Comment: Yes,  I am calling html2canvas after the dom is rendered, but its not working.

Comment: Cloud you post the whole code? , I had a similar problem with that , You can see my code with this link. https://github.com/zackexplosion/angular-rails-blog/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/front/posts/factories/hightlight.js

Comment: The remaining code is nothing but a script calling htmlToCanvas...
 <script type="text/javascript">
 html2canvas(document.getElementById("printers")).then(function(canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        });
</script>

Comment: there is no id with "printers" in your html